# Select JSON from a table using MS SQL FOR JSON

Tags: json, sql-server

I have a table with 2 columns key value and I want to do a SELECT FOR JSON and get the result in {"key": "value"} format

Any idea how to do it?

thank you

table:

```
key | value
-----------
foo | 1
```

expected results:

```
{"foo": "1"}
```

what I tried

```
SELECT key,value FROM table FOR JSON AUTO
```

what was the result

```
{"key":"foo","value":"1"}
```

this solution also works but I am looking for something cleaner

[DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=db837aeeef8ba147ce7eecd29e937f47)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am fetching two columns EMPLOYEEID and EMPLOYEENAME from EMPLOYEE table. Replace columns and table with your details.

```
SELECT STUFF
 (
 (
    SELECT CONCAT(',{"', EMPLOYEEID, '": "', EMPLOYEENAME, '"', '}')
    FROM EMPLOYEE
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
 ).value('.', 'varchar(max)')
 ,1
 ,1
 ,''
 ) + '';
```

Comment: thank you :-) I was just creating a very similar DBfiddle demo